# Why do my pokeballs shake in the battle menu?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

I've noticed, when I'm in a battle, that certain pokeballs shake back and forth.

I'm not talking about when I throw a pokeball to capture a pokemon. I mean when in the middle of a battle and on the bottom screen of the DS where the commands are like in the screenshot I provided.

**What is the significance behind my pokeballs shaking?**

[image: Pokemon battle screen]

Comment: I think it's just a little visual flair, but I also think wounded (yellow/red health) pokemon shake more weakly on that screen. Can't test right now though

Comment: @ DanmakuGrazer The post had already been bumped to the front page and was incorrectly tagged.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I'm talking about the title. I don't see any reason to change the title to this other than clickbait.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I don’t understand how the new title is clickbait? I initially thought the original title referred to pokeballs shaking 3 times when thrown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that that Pokémon has almost enough experience to level up.

I assume that switching to them and winning the battle will give them enough experience, but I can't be sure.